# Issues displaying a dynamically updated HTML input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm struggling to get the behaviour I need - as follows:

A HTML form is pre-populated with a value via jQuery. When the user focuses on the input field I want the form to clear.  On blur from the form, the form should repopulate the form with the existing value.

I have a solution that clears and repopulates the form but it fails as soon as anything is typed in.

This is what I have so far:

```
var x = "Default";

$(function () {

    $("input").attr({
        "value": x
    });

    $("input").focus(function () {
        $("input").attr({
            "value": ""
        });
    });

    $("input").blur(function () {
        $("input").attr({
            "value": x
        });
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thepeted/p74kfdt8/6/

If I look in developer tools, I can see the input value is changing dynamically in the DOM, but in the case that the user has typed something in to the form, the display no longer updates.

I'd love to understand why this is happening (ie, why it works in one case and not the other).  Also, if there is a better way of approaching the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use the placeholder attribute? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, however it appears to result in exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Let me get this clear, you want to remove the value the user has entered once the input loses focus am I right?

Comment: You are playing with attribute, you certainly want to play with property instead...

Comment: You need to add the value like in my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/32497755/2006386  check my demo alsoUse `$('input').attr("value",x);`

Comment: solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/1nn1ehpa/1/

Comment: @StijnBernards yes that's right.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll thanks, however, that still fails for me once I type something in to the box.  ie. it won't clear what I've typed in.

Comment: @Salketer thanks, will read the docs and try that.

Comment: I think LinkinTED's answer is pretty close, if you always want to remove the value the user entered just remove the `if (elem.val() == '')` in the blur function. Keep in mind that this is user unfriendly though.

Comment: I have edited my code please check it now http://stackoverflow.com/a/32497755/2006386

Comment: Thanks @StijnBernards and particularly for pointing out the user-friendliness which I had not considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Stijn, best practice would be to use the placeholder attibute.

However if you do want to use a function for it. I would check on the focus if the value is the default value or not. If so, empty the input, if not, don't do anything.

On blur, you also only want to place the default value back if the value is empty... so check for that aswell.

```js
var x = "Default";

$(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').val(x);

  $('input[type=text]').on('focus', function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.val() == x)
      elem.val('');
  }).on("blur", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.val() == '')
      elem.val(x);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As Stijn mentions in comments to my original question, I have the option of removing the `if (elem.val() == '')` to get the functionality I originally desired, but I am reconsidering now as it is indeed not user friendly.

Comment: Lookout with this solution, as it targets all inputs on the page. Even submit buttons, radios and checkboxes. This might cause very unwanted behaviours.

Comment: Change the selector to `input[type=text]`, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your edited [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4quxjezu/).

updated code:

```
 $("input").blur(function () {
    $("input").val(x);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I'd use the [placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) as everyone pointed out. If you too are facing the need to support older browsers and some others that do not support the placeholder attribute, use this snippet I've made:

```
$('input[placeholder]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.attr('placeholder')).css('color','888888');
    $this.focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))
            $(this).val('').css('color','');
    });
    $this.blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '')
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).css('color','888888');
    });
});
```

This script will find all inputs with a placeholder attribute, give it's value to the input, and add the correct events. I've left the css calls just to show you where to put the codes to mimic the greyed text like modern browsers do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```js
var x = "Default";

$(function () {

    $("input").val(x);

    $("input").focus(function () {
        $("input").val("");
    });

    $("input").blur(function () {
        $("input").val(x);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: This seems to behave exactly the same as my code, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks - that does work now.  So updating the `.attr()` method is not the same as using `.val()` ?

Comment: if it works then please consider a upvote so that it'll be helpful for someone else